# Debug ILRepack merged plugin assembly from Plugin Registration tool

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, .net-4.6.2, ilrepack

I'm trying to debug plugin assembly that been merged via [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack), but Plugin Registration tool's Replay Plug-in Execution throws an error related to `System.Text.Json`:
`` Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Operation could destabilize the runtime. ``

Merging command looks like this:

```
<Target Name="ILRepack" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="ILRepack is running..." />
    <ItemGroup>
        <ILRepackPackage Include="..\packages\ILRepack.2.0.18\tools\ILRepack.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists(@(ILRepackPackage->'%(FullPath)'))" Text="You are trying to use the ILRepack package, but it is not installed or at the correct location." />
    <Exec Command="@(ILRepackPackage->'%(FullPath)') /out:$(OutputPath)Merged\$(AssemblyName).dll $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll <...AND ALL OTHER ASSEMBLIES> /parallel /wildcards /target:library /keyfile:NPDKey.snk" />
</Target>
```

Code execution works fine in Dynamics 365 CE (online), only Plugin replay is throwing an error.

I tried:

1. Debug non-merged assembly, that did not help.
2. Debug non-signed merged assembly, that did not help.
3. To not use ILRepack, but that made it even worse.
4. To use different merge tools like `ILRepect.Lib.MSBuild.Task` or `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task` but those have same effect.

Here's some code that throws actual error:

```
var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(object);
```

Version of `System.Text.Json` is 6.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot more of research I found out that I can debug ILRepack merged assembly by the Replay Plug-in Execution feature in Plugin Registration tool. However in Settings tab, Isolation Mode must be selected as "none", see image below.

[image: Replay Plug-in Execution Settings tab]